# GPS time in iOS

Tags: ios, time, gps

i have a question about the coreLocation framework. 
In my app i get the gps coordinates of my iPad and show them in a view. Each time "didUpdateLocation" of the locationManager is called i update my view. Is it possible to get the actual gps time too? The CLLocation which is send in an NSArray in "didUpdateLocation" has the property "timeStamp" but this is only the timestamp when "The time at which this location was determined.(Apple Documentation)" When i show these time values on the view and compare all the values with an radio controlled clock i see a time difference of about 1-2 seconds.

Is it possible to get the "correct" time to show on the view???

Thanks, Benjamin

Comment: any further questions to that topic, where my answer did not help?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get the original timestamp of the GPS location.

However the position and the time delivered by apple do match.
For whatever reason the whole location (including its time) is delay for 1-2 seconds

(The timestamp of the GPS receiver would be in UTC (or GPS time), but Apple corrects according to time zone setting.)